# Migrate npm repository from a GCP project to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, npm-package, google-artifact-registry

I have a npm repository in GCP Artifact Registry in a project and I want to migrate this repository to another project, I have permission of both projects. I tried with export and gcloud cp, but didn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: when you migrate images between projects in Artifact Registry, the corresponding repositories are also migrated automatically.Have a look at this [document1](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/copy-images) & [document2](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/store-nodejs#config)

Comment: The first document is about copying images from one repository to another, but what I want to copy are not images, but NPM packages in the Artifact Registry. The second document is about uploading packages to the Artifact Registry, but that is done one by one. I have over 100 packages in the Artifact Registry of one project, and I want to copy them to another project.

Comment: Seem there is no  direct migration to move an npm repository from one project to another.instead make the copy in GCS (perhaps via a tool like GCSFuse) and then use [gcloud artifacts apt import](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/apt/import).you  can also check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#third-party) it twill use  for a third party integration